# Match keys in a hash to return respective key+value in perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a hash. I want to get key and values by matching string pattern of keys.

For example, I have a Hash like this

```
 my %hash =  { FIELDN1 = > "N1", FIELDN2 => "N2", FIELDM1 => "M1", FILEDM2 =>"M2"}
```

I want to get key and value having 1 in the keys as given below.

```
{ FIELDN1 = > "N1", FIELDM1 => "M1" }
```

Comment: Why use regex? Why not loop over keys,values of hash and check if the last character is number 1?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: How would you check whether the last character is `1` without a regex? I can't imagine anything clearer than `/1$/`. Something like `substr($_, -1) eq '1'` is very clunky in comparison.

Comment: Yeah i was taking about substring with a python paradigm. And I agree with you, in perl a regex would be much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do as you ask

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %hash = ( FIELDN1 => "N1", FIELDN2 => "N2", FIELDM1 => "M1", FILEDM2 => "M2" );

my %subset = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } grep { /1$/ } keys %hash;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%subset;
```

#### output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FIELDN1' => 'N1',
          'FIELDM1' => 'M1'
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to need the keys whose corresponding values satisfy the requirement, you might be better off saving them separately:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash =  (
    FIELDN1 => "N1",
    FIELDN2 => "N2",
    FIELDM1 => "M1",
    FILEDM2 => "M2",
);

my @subset_keys = grep /1\z/, keys %hash;

my %subset;
@subset{ @subset_keys } = @hash{ @subset_keys };

# contrived example for needing the matching keys    
for my $k ( @subset_keys ) {
    print "$k = $subset{$k}\n";
}
```

If you also want to remove the matching keys from `%hash`, use:

```
@subset{ @subset_keys } = delete @hash{ @subset_keys };
```

Or, if you just want to remove the non-matching entries from `%hash`:

```
delete @hash{ grep !/1\z/, keys %hash };
```

`%hash` will now contain:

```
---
FIELDM1: M1
FIELDN1: N1
```